# Why am I getting '{' and ';' errors in this code using visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, directx

So basically I am watching a DirectX course video and I am copying exactly what the person is doing, so everything was fine til I added a Message code. The video was made in 2018 so maybe there have been some code changes? I don't know and I am really frustrated because I have tried my best to fix it.
Here's the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage( 69 );
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam );
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hIstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    const auto pClassName = "directX12";
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hIstance;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = pClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0, pClassName,
        "Happy Hard Window",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        200, 200, 640, 480,
        nullptr, nullptr, hIstance, nullptr
    );
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    MSG msg;
    BOOL gResult;
    while( (gResult = GetMessage( &msg,nullptr,0,0 ) > 0 ) {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    if(gResult == -1 ) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return msg.wParam;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Could you please help me? I am tried of this -.-

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please include the error message in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line

```
while( (gResult = GetMessage( &msg,nullptr,0,0 ) > 0 ) {
```

Count the number of `(` and the number of `)`.

In the long run you'll learn more by trying to do less. DirectX is not something I would recommend until you've got a firm grasp of the language.

Comment: meh, beat me by 2 seconds :P

Comment: OMGOMGOMGOOGMGMOGMGOMGGOGM THXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
while( (gResult = GetMessage( &msg,nullptr,0,0 ) > 0 ) {
```

Has three opening brackets and two closing